# angular.js parsing value in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a list of actions in a child controller:

```
$scope.actions = [{action:"onClick()",name:"Test"}];
```

On a browse template i have a button dropdown group that looks like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="action in actions">
  <a href="" ng-click="action.action">{{action.name}}</a>
</li>
```

The problem that I'm having is that ng-click should call, in this example the `onClick()` function, but if i put `ng-click="{{action.action}}"` it breaks.

Is this even possible?

Comment: First, you have a type, should be `actions.action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: my bad, you don't have a typo.

You don't need `{{}}` if it's an attribute of the element. But I'm really not sure what you expect to happen when you try to call a string, it needs to be a function.

Try something like this:

```
var someFunc = function() {
    console.log("someFunc")
};

$scope.actions = [{action:someFunc,name:"Test"}];

<li ng-repeat="action in actions">
  <a href="" ng-click="action.action()">{{action.name}}</a>
</li>
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a5gJ7/1/).

Comment: Jp, that works, have to be careful of the order, first function, then setting actions. thx

Answer (score 0):

Did you define onClick function, something like

```
$scope.onClick = function() {
 alert('clicked!');
};
```

BTW, original syntax for ngClick is correct, without double curly brackets.

Comment: try replacing   action:"onClick()"   with   action: onClick